# Coffeescript and Passport: Strange behaviour, attaching functions

Tags: express, coffeescript, passport.js

I have been playing around with coffescript, express and passport and it seems I don't really get some details of the language.

Can somebody explain to me, what's going on here?

When I initialize the `passport.serializeUser` and `passport.deserializeUser` functions like this:

```
passport.serializeUser (user, done)->
  done null, user

passport.deserializeUser (obj, done)->
  done null, obj
```

everything works as expected.

But I want to pass those functions in from elsewhere.
As soon as I do the following, which to my mind should be exactly the same, I get a TypeError, telling me that: "TypeError: object is not a function" when passport tries to call my deserialize function.

```
serialize = (user, done) ->
  done null, user

deserialize = (obj,  done) ->
  done null, obj

passport.serializeUser = serialize
passport.deserializeUser = deserialize
```

I am out of ideas. What is the difference here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These:

```
passport.serializeUser (user, done)->
  done null, user

passport.deserializeUser (obj, done)->
  done null, obj
```

are calling the `serializeUser` and `deserializeUser` methods of `passport` and passing them functions as arguments. They're the same as:

```
s = (user, done) -> done(null, user)
passport.serializeUser(s)

d = (obj, done) -> done(null, obj)
passport.deserializeUser(d)
```

These:

```
serialize = (user, done) -> done null, user
passport.serializeUser = serialize

deserialize = (obj,  done) -> done null, obj
passport.deserializeUser = deserialize
```

are assigning new functions to `passport`'s `serializeUser` and `deserializeUser` properties.

So the first is calling some functions with functions as arguments and the second is overwriting some properties (which happen to be functions) with other functions.

Comment: Argh... You are of course correct. Thx.

With my assignments now being:
    passport.serializeUser serialize
    passport.deserializeUser deserialize

instead of:
    passport.serializeUser = serialize
    passport.deserializeUser = deserialize

All it well.

:)